# Show that the definition of $z!$ for Re($z$) $\leq −1$ is independent of the value of $n$ chosen.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, factorial, gamma-function

The complex function $z!$ is defined by

$z!=\int_{0}^{\infty}u^ze^{-u}du$

for  Re($z$)$>-1$

For Re($z$)$≤ −1$ it is defined by

$z!=\frac{(z+n)!}{(z+n)(z+n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(z+1)}$

where $n$ is any (positive) integer $>$ −Re $z$. Being the ratio of two polynomials, $z!$
is analytic everywhere in the finite complex plane except at the poles that occur
when $z$ is a negative integer.

Show that the definition of $z!$ for Re $z ≤ −1$ is independent of the value of $n$ chosen.

Proof:

Let $m$ and $n$ be two choices of integer with $m>n> −$Re $z$. Denote the
corresponding definitions of $z!$ by $(z!)_m$ and $(z!)_n$ and consider the ratio of these
two functions:

$\frac{(z!)_m}{(z!)_n}=\left(\frac{(z+m)!}{(z+m)(z+m-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(z+1)}\right)\left(\frac{(z+n)(z+n-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(z+1)}{(z+n)!}\right)=\frac{(z+m)!}{(z+m)(z+m-1)\cdot\cdot\cdot(z+n+1)\times(z+n)!}=\frac{(z+m)!}{(z+m)!}$

But I can't understand the second and third parts. I do not understand how that happens or what is used to get there. Could you help me?

Comment: First show that $(z+1)! = (z+1) z!$ for $\operatorname{Re} z > -1$.

Comment: @MartinR I just proved it. How can I use that result?

Comment: *Some* feedback on the answer would be nice :)

Answer (score 2):

The key point is that $(z+1)! = (z+1) z!$ for $\operatorname{Re} z > -1$ which can be shown using integration by parts. (This is equivalent to the functional equation $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ for $\operatorname{Re} z > 0$ of the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)).

For $m > n > -\operatorname{Re} z$ we then have
$$
(z+m)! = (z+m)(z+m-1)! = (z+m)(z+m-1)(z+m-2)! \\
= \ldots = (z+m)(z+m-1)\cdots(z+n+1) (z+n)!
$$
and therefore
$$
\require{cancel}
 (z!)_m = \frac{(z+m)!}{(z+m)\cdots (z+n+1)(z+n)\cdots (z+1)}\\
=  \frac{\cancel{(z+m)}\cdots\cancel{(z+n+1)} (z+n)!}{\cancel{(z+m)}\cdots \cancel{(z+n+1)}(z+n)\cdots (z+1)} = (z!)_n
$$
so that the definition is independent of the choice of $n$.